# html2canvas sometimes not capturing content + text quality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas, todataurl

I'm trying to create a 'save div as png' function in JavaScript angular with html2canvas. 
It 'almost' works, except for the image quality could be better (mostly text)

**BUT** sometimes it just opens an empty canvas not capturing the elements inside.

Instead of using the download function i tried to just window.open(data) and i still just opens a new window with an empty canvas.
i also confirmed that the id is received on failing 'save as png divs'.

```
  $scope.savePNG = function(id) {
    var target = document.getElementById(id);

    html2canvas(target, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
        // data is the Base64-encoded image
        download(data, "Graph.png", "image/png");
        // window.open(data);
      }
    });
  };


  function download(data, filename, filetype) {
    // create an "off-screen" anchor tag
    var lnk = document.createElement('a');

    // the key here is to set the download attribute of the a tag
    lnk.download = filename;

    lnk.href = data;

    // create a "fake" click-event to trigger the download
    if (document.createEvent) {
      var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false,
        false, 0, null);

      lnk.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (lnk.fireEvent) {
      lnk.fireEvent("onclick");
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you sure your elements are ready in the DOM when you save as .. ?

Comment: could you post some of your html ?

Comment: @Lulylulu Yes, the DOM has finished loading before the request is fired.

Comment: @AndersPedersen, Hi, do you have any solution for this? The same thing happens to me with html2canvas 1.0.0-rc.5